# How to use TDataSet.DisableControls with Master/Detail datasets?

Tags: delphi, tdataset

Calling `TDataSet.DisableControls` disables the link between master/detail datasets. Is there another way to disable updating data-aware controls without affecting the master/detail relationship? I know I can set individual component's `DataSource` to `nil`, but this isn't the practical way for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution presumes you use separate `TDataSource` instances for linking UI controls and for Master-Detail relations which - from a design perspective - is a good idea anyway.

The drawback of this solution: this cause some flickering in your UI.

You could:

1. Enumerate all `TDataSource` instances that point to your `TDataSet` instances but are not involved in Master-Detail relations.
2. For each of those instances, save the [`Enabled`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSource.Enabled) property.
3. For each of those instances, set the `Enabled` property to `False`
4. Run your logic
5. For each of those instances, restore the `Enabled` property.

Comment: Seems like a good idea to write a class which can enumerate datasources and maintain these links.  Then instantiate an instance per data module that needs such management tasks.

Comment: Neat idea, but not practical in my case. I have a database action which duplicates the current record of associated dataset, with all of the corresponding detail records. I have no idea if the user has twin datasources per dataset or not.

Comment: Duplication of data usually is not such a good idea. Why do you need that?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you have a perfect option to achieve this. As the Delphi Help states:

> If the dataset is the master of a master/detail relationship, calling DisableControls also disables the master/detail relationship. Setting BlockReadSize instead of calling DisableControls updates the detail datasets as you scroll through the dataset, but does not update data-aware controls.